# how to get data PostCode last two after two space sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have following query i want only highlighted post code how to get this please help me  i want result like this Via1: PostCode, Via2 :PostCode ,Via3: PostCode

```
SELECT    
  STUFF((  
    SELECT  ' , Via ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  t1.BookingId asc) AS VARCHAR(4))+  
           ' : ' +  t2.ViaLocValue    
    FROM Booking_ViaLocations t2  
    WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookingId  
    FOR XML PATH (''))  
  ,1,2,'') AS Names  
FROM Booking_ViaLocations t1  
WHERE t1.BookingId = b.Id  
GROUP BY t1.BookingId
```

please see below image i have more then ones via point addresses and i want  get highlighted postcode from address anyone help me, i am very thankful to you

[image]

i was try this query but its show error Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

```
CREATE TABLE booking
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
address varchar(255) 

)

insert into booking values('NORTHWICK AVENUE HARROW HA3 0AB')
insert into booking values('CHANCERY LANE LONDON WC2A 1AB')

CREATE TABLE Booking_ViaLocations
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BookingId  int,
ViaLocations varchar(255) 

)

insert into Booking_ViaLocations values (1,'NORTHWICK AVENUE HARROW HA3 0AB')
insert into Booking_ViaLocations values (1,'CHANCERY LANE LONDON WC2A 1AB')
insert into Booking_ViaLocations values (1,'NEW OXFORD STREET LONDON WC1A 1BA')



 SELECT    
      STUFF(  (  
                SELECT  ' , Via ' 
                        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                               (ORDER BY  t1.BookingId asc) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
                        + ' : ' +  
         right(t2.ViaLocValue, 
         charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocValue), 
         charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocValue)) + 1) - 1)
                FROM  Booking_ViaLocations t2  
                WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookingId  
                FOR XML PATH ('')
               )  
              ,1,2,'') AS Names  
  FROM   Booking_ViaLocations t1  

  inner join Booking b on
 t1.BookingId = b.Id  
GROUP BY t1.BookingId
```

Comment: Is it always last two words at the end of string

Comment: Instead of posting image please post the data. It help us to easily copy paste the data to test

Comment: yes i want these postcode

Comment: @Mr Khan, you could look at finding the position of the second space in the string from the right. But, you really should not be doing this. The data WILL be stored with the post code in a separate field in the database, you just need to go to the source table and read it from there

Comment: @MRKhan  If the size of post code is fixed then you only need to  right(your_column_name ,size)

Comment: how to add below query in my Query ? i want add below query  in my above query

Comment: please show us your expected result. Expecially for those rows where Names has multiple `Post Code` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the last 2 word of a string, use charindex() twice on the reverse string

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'MERTON RD HARROW HA2 0AA'

select  right(@str, charindex(' ', reverse(@str), charindex(' ', reverse(@str)) + 1) - 1)
```

to incorporate this into your existing query, the following uses CTE

```
; with cte as
(
  -- your existing query
  SELECT    
          STUFF(  (  
                    SELECT  ' , Via ' 
                            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                   (ORDER BY  t1.BookingId asc) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
                            + ' : ' +  t2.ViaLocValue    
                    FROM  Booking_ViaLocations t2  
                    WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookingId  
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                   )  
                  ,1,2,'') AS Names  
  FROM   Booking_ViaLocations t1  
  WHERE  t1.BookingId = b.Id  
  GROUP BY t1.BookingId
)
select *,
       right(Names, 
             charindex(' ', reverse(Names), 
             charindex(' ', reverse(Names)) + 1) - 1) as PostCode
from   cte
```

Query 3:

```
  SELECT    
          STUFF(  (  
                    SELECT  ' , Via ' 
                            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                   (ORDER BY  t1.BookingId asc) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
                            + ' : ' +  
             right('  ' + t2.ViaLocValue, 
             charindex(' ', reverse('  ' + t2.ViaLocValue), 
             charindex(' ', reverse('  ' + t2.ViaLocValue)) + 1) - 1)
                    FROM  Booking_ViaLocations t2  
                    WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookingId  
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                   )  
                  ,1,2,'') AS Names  
  FROM   Booking_ViaLocations t1  
  WHERE  t1.BookingId = b.Id  
  GROUP BY t1.BookingId
```

Comment: @MRKhan use CTE or derived query

Comment: i am new in sql, check above query and picture how to get this in my query

Comment: its return only last postcode but i have more then one postcode in one line check above picture please

Comment: And would you mind tell us what is that error messages so that we can help you fix it ?

Comment: oh. . you have updated the picture. So what does your expected result looks like ?

Comment: see lastest Query 3

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: i am providing you dummy table check

Answer (score 1):

```
---------- Query Without Error
SELECT
STUFF( (
SELECT ' , Via '
+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER
(ORDER BY t1.BookingId asc) AS VARCHAR(4))
+ ' : ' +
--------------- Added CASE Statement to check if CharIndex is zero
    (
    CASE WHEN charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocations), charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocations)) + 1) > 0 THEN 
        right(t2.ViaLocations,charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocations), charindex(' ', reverse(t2.ViaLocations)) + 1) - 1)
    ELSE 
        null
    END
    )
--------------- Ends here
FROM Booking_ViaLocations t2
WHERE t2.BookingId = t1.BookingId
FOR XML PATH ('')
)
,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Booking_ViaLocations t1

inner join Booking b on
t1.BookingId = b.Id
GROUP BY t1.BookingId
```